# File not found - MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

i received the following error on some Sharepoint Pages

File Not Found.   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) 
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) 
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) 
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) 
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) 
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(String assemblyName, Boolean throwOnFail) 
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.LoadAssembly(String assemblyName, Boolean throwOnFail) 
   at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.ProcessTagNamespaceRegistrationCore(TagNamespaceRegisterEntry nsRegisterEntry) 
   at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.ProcessTagNamespaceRegistration(TagNamespaceRegisterEntry nsRegisterEntry) 
   at System.Web.UI.BaseTemplateParser.ProcessDirective(String directiveName, IDictionary directive) 
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateControlParser.ProcessDirective(String directiveName, IDictionary directive) 
   at System.Web.UI.PageParser.ProcessDirective(String directiveName, IDictionary directive) 
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)

I used Assembly Binding Log Viewer Tool (fuslogvw.exe) to locate the assembly which is not bound and the assembly seems to be Microsoft.Sharepoint.Intl.Resources.dll. This assemlby is not being located by the application resulting in 'File not Found' error.

Can anyone guide me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the assembly is in the GAC?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have checked GAC for this assembly. I found Microsoft.Sharepoint.Intl.dll but **Microsoft.Sharepoint.Intl.Resources.dll** was not found.

Answer (score 0):

Ok have you installed the language packs? Look for the assembly and try adding the assembly to the GAC if not try installing the language packs.